# How to Create a Rails Dropdown Filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropdownbox

I am trying to create a dropdown filter in Rails 3.2.

I have seen solutions along these lines, but am unsure about how to implement them in my case.
[Filter results on index page from dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846383/filter-results-on-index-page-from-dropdown).

I have a table of `events` and I'd like a dropdown box to filter those events by `category`. I am half way there by doing something along these lines in the view using params:

```
<% @event.events_by_category(sanitize_output(params[:cat])).each do |e| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

And then using the following in the `event` model:

```
def self.events_by_category(cat)
  if cat == nil
    all
  else
    where("category = ?", cat)
  end
end
```

However, creating a dropdown that refreshes the URL to include params in jQuery seems very dirty.

What's the best way to accomplish this type of dropdown in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`form_tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) for this:

```
<%= form_tag events_path, method: 'get' do %>
  <%= select_tag :cat, Options::TYPE %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Filter' %>
<% end %>
```