# Filter results on index from dropdown with categorization

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to accomplish something similar to this:
[Filter results on index page from dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846383/filter-results-on-index-page-from-dropdown)

However, the above example is for two models where each "area" has many "venues" and each "venue" belongs to one area.

My own models are Image, Category, and Categorization set up the same way as outlined by Ryan Bates in this episode http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many . I opted to go with the has_many :through relation.

How would I go about modifying the code from the above answer to work with my Categorization table?

Thanks!

Code (Relevant parts):

```
#image model
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
end

#image controller
def index
  @images = Image.where("approved = true").order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
end

#category model
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :images, :through => :categorizations
end

#Categorization model
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :image
    belongs_to :category
end
```

Comment: Show code for your HTML search, your index controller action, and model code for `Image`. A rough guess: `Image.joins(:categories).where(categories: { id: <ID> })`

Comment: Updated with the relevant portions of code